Ubuntu 22.04 squid proxy configuration in DMZ, for disconnected environment
I have an infrastructure with a DMZ, where the squid proxy is housed there. There is internal I have machines that go out through that proxy. The configuration is next.
# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12      # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#
include /etc/squid/conf.d/*.conf

# For example, to allow access from your local networks, you may uncomment the
# following rule (and/or add rules that match your definition of "local"):
# http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

#REGLA o ACL PARA REALIZAR DESCARGAS
#http_access allow all
acl all_updates url_regex -i "/etc/squid/all_updates"
http_access allow all_updates


# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all


# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#
include /etc/squid/conf.d/*.conf

# For example, to allow access from your local networks, you may uncomment the
# following rule (and/or add rules that match your definition of "local"):
# http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

#REGLA o ACL PARA REALIZAR DESCARGAS
#http_access allow all
acl all_updates url_regex -i "/etc/squid/all_updates"
http_access allow all_updates


# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern \/(Packages|Sources)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/Release(|\.gpg)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/InRelease$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/(Translation-.*)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
# example pattern for deb packages
#refresh_pattern (\.deb|\.udeb)$   129600 100% 129600
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

When trying to update the machine, I show these errors
failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dist/jammy-security/inrelease 403 Forbidden IP...

